# Concatenating text and binary data into one file

Tags: c++, file-io, binaryfiles

I am developing an application, and I have several pieces of data that I want to be able to save to and open from the same file. The first is several lines that are essentially human readable that store simple data about certain attributes. The data is stored in `AttributeList` objects that support `operator<<` and `operator>>`. The rest are .png images which I have loaded into memory.

How can I save all this data to one file in such a way that I can then easily read it back into memory? Is there a way to store the image data in memory that will make this easier?

Comment: Why do you want images in the same file as attributes? Seems like poor design to do it like that. Is there a reason or is this an aim at simplicity?

Comment: @EastonBornemeier I want the user to be able to open a single file that contains all the data. I want it to be simple for users to share files with each other and not have to worry about keeping multiple files together for a single project.

Comment: One way to do it is to reserve a block of data (say 1024 bytes) at the start of the file. Obviously, this work only if text size is known and small enough.

Comment: @KaiSchmidt -- Spec out your file structure.  The first 1,024 bytes (or whatever you decide on) is text describing the file.  From byte 1,024 till the end is binary image data.  If you inspect certain well-known image formats such as TIFF or JPEG, they also have a block reserve for user text.

Comment: Why not use a zip or tar file?

Comment: @EdHeal Would it be reasonable to ask my users to do that? It may sound like a rhetorical question, but it's not.

Comment: You can change the extension. Get the application to unzip it.  Word documents are xml zipped files

Comment: And there are libraries to most of this in memory

Comment: There are a lot of formats which are “secretly” ZIP files: newer Microsoft Office documents (the ones with an `x` at the end of the extension), the formats of the main competition office suite LibreOffice or OpenOffice, EPUB files (a popular ebook format), even Java’s JAR files. The users don’t need to care about the difference, unless you want them to be able to open the file in a text editor and edit the human-readable parts themselves.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I save all this data to one file in such a way that I can then
>   easily read it back into memory? Is there a way to store the image
>   data in memory that will make this easier?

Yes.

In an embedded system I once worked on, the requirement was to capture sysstem configuration into a ram file system. (1 Meg byte)

We used zlib to compress and 'merge' multiple files into a single storage file.

Perhaps any compression system can work for you.  On Linux, I would use popen() to run gzip or gunzip, etc.

---

update 2017-08-07

In my popen demo (for this question), I build the command string with standard shell commands:

```
std::string cmd;
cmd += "tar -cvf dumy514DEMO.tar dumy*V?.cc ; gzip dumy514DEMO.tar ; ls -lsa *.tar.gz";
//      tar without compression             ; next do compress
```

Then construct my popen-wrapped-in-a-class instance and invoke the popen read action.  There is normally very little feedback to the user (as is the style of UNIX Philosophy, i.e. no success messages), so I included (for this demo) the -v (for verbose option). The resulting feedback lists the 4 files tar'd together, and I list the resulting .gz file.

```
dumy514V0.cc
dumy514V1.cc
dumy514V2.cc
dumy514V3.cc
8 -rw-rw-r-- 1 dmoen dmoen 7983 Aug  7 17:23 dumy514DEMO.tar.gz
```

And a snippet from the dir listing shows my executable, my source code, and the newly created tar.gz.

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 dmoen dmoen 86416 Aug  7 17:18 dumy514DEMO
-rw-rw-r--  1 dmoen dmoen 13576 Aug  7 17:18 dumy514DEMO.cc
-rw-rw-r--  1 dmoen dmoen  7983 Aug  7 17:23 dumy514DEMO.tar.gz
```

As you can see, the tar.gz is about 8000 bytes.  The 4 files add to about 70,000 bytes.

Comment: It’s probably better to use a programmatic library than a `popen` call, and almost certainly easier to port between Linux and Windows if necessary.

Comment: I easily found a Windows '_popen()' on the web.  I quit trying to compile it on Ubuntu 15.10, using g++v5 after about the 5th unsolvable error.

Comment: Which is why I said using a library for it would probably be better. It would take me at least 5 unsolvable errors to get an external program to work on Windows, but I could code it for Linux fairly easily. A library would be more likely to just work in whatever locations it claimed it worked.